# @tippy.js/react allowHTML

Tags: reactjs, tippyjs

In react Tippy I cannot make work some properties of tippy. I want allowHTML in Tippy.

Here is my code:

```
    <Tippy
        // content={<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: tooltip}} />}
        content={tooltip}
        delay={100}
        hideOnClick={false}
        allowHTML={true}
        
    >
        ...some other code here
    </Tippy>
```

The commented code does what I would like to see. If the content contains html then it renders the content properly. I have found the solution here: https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs-react/issues/94#issuecomment-498100958

However, I would like to use the own properties of tippy.
**allowHTML** does not work while **delay** and **hideOnClick** work.

It seems like the properties with "*R*" (see attached picture) do not seem to work and I cannot figure out how to use them in react and could not find in documentation either.

[Tippy properties V6.x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIYnj.png)

Source: https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/all-props/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main issue with dangerouslySetInnerHTML was XSS vulnerability. That's why I wanted to use own property of tippyjs, the innerHTML. Because I though it handles XSS vulnerability but after reading the documentation again, more carefully, I realized it requires sanitizing data as well.

So I just go with dangerouslySetInnerHTML and sanitize my data before using it.
Here is my code:

```
import Tippy from '@tippy.js/react';
import dompurify from 'dompurify';
import React from 'react';

const PropertyLabel = ({ label, tooltip }) => {
    const sanitizedTooltip = dompurify.sanitize(tooltip);
    return (
        <Tippy
            content={<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitizedTooltip }} />}
            delay={100}
        >
        ...some other code here
        </Tippy>
    );
};
```

Here are the sources that I used to implement dompurify:

- https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/spasecurity/react-xss-part2.html
- [https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml:~:text=class%20attribute%20instead.-,dangerouslySetInnerHTML,-dangerouslySetInnerHTML%20is%20React%E2%80%99s](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml:%7E:text=class%20attribute%20instead.-,dangerouslySetInnerHTML,-dangerouslySetInnerHTML%20is%20React%E2%80%99s)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify

I know it does not solve the problem of using properties of Tippy marked with an "R" in React, but this single solution works instead of "allowHTML" property.